# mysql use IF after SET only if condition is true

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this query is not correct, but how should I write it?

```
UPDATE OFFER SET
IF(St != 3, St = 2 AND View = '$userupdate' AND Date_V_E = '$date', '')
WHERE Id = '$entryID'
```

The `IF` should be like this:

```
if(St != 3){
   St = 2;
   View = '$userupdate';
   Date_V_E = '$date';
}else{
   //DO NOTHING
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE OFFER 
SET St = 2, 
    View = '$userupdate', 
    Date_V_E = '$date'
WHERE Id = '$entryID'
and St <> 3
```